# Imageview is not overlapping CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to overlap an imageview on Cardview by using RelativeLayout but the imageview is displaying behind that CardView. I am loading a gif on this imageview by using glide:

```
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.practice_listen).into(subCat1_anim)
```

and the part of layout.xml is:

```
         <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="281dp"
                android:layout_height="237dp"
                >

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/subCat1"
                        android:layout_width="189.5dp"
                        android:layout_height="189.5dp" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/subCat1_anim"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Now the problem is the subCat1_anim should overlap the cardview but the cardview is overalapping it. So what i am doing wrong here? Please help!

Comment: use constraintslayout instead

Comment: ok let me try with it.

Comment: tried wth constraintlayout but still it is the same

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="281dp"
    android:layout_height="237dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="189.5dp"
        android:layout_height="189.5dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/subCat1"
            android:layout_width="189.5dp"
            android:layout_height="189.5dp" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subCat1_anim"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```